# Does this proof fail if $H$ is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, infinite-groups

The following is from Abstract Algebra (Dummit & Foote):

If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $H=\langle S\rangle$ for some $S\subseteq G$, then prove that $H\unlhd G$ iff $gSg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$.

When considering the proof, it seems that the condition that $G$ is finite is never explicitly used, although there is a part of the proof that might be ambiguous in cases where $H$ is not finitely generated:

Proof ($\Leftarrow$):  Suppose that $H\leq G$ and $H=\langle S\rangle$ for some $S\subseteq G$. Suppose also that  $gSg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$. Let $g\in G$, $h\in H$. Then $h=a_1^{n_1}\cdot a_2^{n_2}\cdots a_k^{n_k}$ for some collection of $a_i\in S$. Here, we compute $ghg^{-1}$ and show by induction (or semantics) that $ghg^{-1}\in H$ by sneaking a $g^{-1}g$ in between each term: $$ghg^{-1}=g\cdot a_1^{n_1}\cdot a_2^{n_2}\cdots a_k^{n_k}\cdot g^{-1}=ga_1g^{-1}ga_1\cdots ga_ng^{-1}\in H$$
My question is, does this argument fail if $H$ is not finitely generated? Why does the author use "G is finite" in the hypothesis, and is this condition necessary? If the condition is necessary, can anyone think of a clever counterexample for the infinite case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the set of elements $x \in G$, such that $gxg^{-1} \in H$ holds for any $g \in G$. This is a subgroup of $G$ (to be precise it is the intersection of pre-images of $H$ with respect to the conjugation with $g$ for all $g \in G$), which contains $S$ by assumption. Hence this subgroup contains $\langle S \rangle =H$. No need for $G$ to be finite or finitely generated.

Comment: Most trivial: $gSg^{-1}\subseteq H \implies gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$.

Comment: And the forward direction, too... I wonder why the author uses the weaker hypothesis?

Comment: @reluctantmathematician Why wouldn't the author use the weakest hypothesis he can get away with? (Or did you mean to wonder why he uses a **stronger** hypothesis?)

Comment: Would it be appropriate  to say that a "weaker hypothesis" results in a "stronger statement"?

Answer (score 1):

Since the map $\varphi\colon G\to G$ defined by $\varphi(x)=gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$, you have that
$$
\varphi(\langle S\rangle)=\langle \varphi(S)\rangle\tag{$*$}
$$
for any subset $S$ of $G$. In your case you know that $\varphi(S)\subseteq H$, so
$$
H\supseteq\langle \varphi(S)\rangle=\varphi(\langle S\rangle)
=\varphi(H)=gHg^{-1}
$$
Since this holds for all $g\in G$, normality is proved.

The proof of $(*)$ doesn't need $S$ to be finite (and $\varphi$ can be any homomorphism, actually). You can prove it using the fact is that an element of $\langle S\rangle$ can be represented as $s_1s_2\dots s_k$, for $s_i\in S$ or $s_i^{-1}\in S$.

There's a more general technique, however. Let $f\colon G\to G'$ be a group homomorphism and $S$ a subset of $G$. The subgroup $\langle f(S)\rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $G'$ containing $f(S)$. Since $f(\langle S\rangle)$ is a subgroup of $G'$ containing $f(S)$, we have $\langle f(S)\rangle\subseteq f(\langle S\rangle)$. Conversely, $f^{-1}(\langle f(S)\rangle)$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $S$, so $\langle S\rangle\subseteq f^{-1}(\langle f(S)\rangle)$ which entails $f(\langle S\rangle)\subseteq \langle f(S)\rangle$.

Note that once you have proved the result in this form, the same argument will work for any algebraic structure, such as rings, vector spaces and so on.

Comment: I have to highly disagree with the last sentence. This is indeed NOT the relevant fact.
When we want to deduce something from some information on generators, we always can define the set of "good" elements, then show this set is a group (ring, vector space, ideal, field, sigma algebra, whatsoever...), and then deduce the result. This works everytime the same and we do not care at all how an arbitrary element looks in terms of generators (for a sigma algebra for instance, we cannot even write down an arbitrary element in general)

Comment: @MooS I concur with your remark; my observation was based on how the OP was trying to prove the fact. I'll reword.

Comment: @MooS However, I have to disagree about how you think to apply the result: the image of an ideal under a ring homomorphism is not generally an ideal. The result is about *subalgebras*.

Comment: How does the fact that the homomorphic image of an ideal is not an ideal relate to my comment?

Comment: @MooS “[...] group (ring, vector space, *ideal*, field, sigma algebra, whatsoever...) [...]” (italic added by me).